# Query all teams using Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I would like to query all the teams in Office 365. There is no endpoint in graph to run such a query. The only supported ones are for joined teams

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/joinedTeams

I also noticed the graph endpoint to query all groups

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups

which seems to list the teams as well. So what is the difference between groups and teams?

Comment: Please have a look at [Get List of All Teams](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/teams_list_all_teams) API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a list of all groups in the organization that have teams, get a list of all groups and then in code find the ones that have a resourceProvisioningOptions property that contains "Team".

Please check API docs to [List all teams in Microsoft Teams for an organization](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/teams_list_all_teams).